# Finding average of a certain array

Tags: c

im trying to find the average coffee drank by the programmers. I can find and display the average but it just seems wrong, the way it is displayed. I just can't manage to extract the last line which displays the average.

```
char poste[]={'A','P','A','P','A','O','P','P','O'};
int nbCafe[]={3,5,2,1,7,1,0,3,2};
int progonly=0;
float progmoyenne=0;

for(i=0;i<9;i++){
   if (poste[i]=='P'){
       progonly+=nbCafe[i];
       progmoyenne=progonly/4.0;}
printf("%f\n",progmoyenne);}
```

The execution gives this.(the last line is the average coffee drank):

```
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.250000
0.250000
1.000000
2.250000
```

Comment: you mean that only the average to be displayed instead of all those values?

Comment: "progmoyenne=progonly/4.0" what's this for?

Comment: `printf` should be outside the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display the average, then just print the average. Move the printf outside the for loop.

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
   if (poste[i]=='P')
   {
       progonly+=nbCafe[i];
       progmoyenne=progonly/4.0;
   }
}
printf("%f\n",progmoyenne);
```

Answer (score 0):

put `printf` outside the `for` loop. Also do declare i using `int i;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
for(cnt=i=0;i<9;i++){
    if (poste[i]=='P'){
        progonly+=nbCafe[i];
        progmoyenne=progonly/(float)++cnt;
        printf("%f\n",progmoyenne);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
5.000000
3.000000
2.000000
2.250000
```